Postgres streaming and logical replication on same host & synchronous replication for both
On the case, when i have a primary postgres, and two other slaves, for one slave, i want to setting up streaming replication from primary, for other slave, i want logical replucation subscription from primary publication.
My question, how its possible to setting up both streaming replication & logical replication but synchronously, whereas, we can't have multiple entries on synchronous_standby_names parameter, this paramerter, must be  setted up on primary.
Thanks in advance
Postgres streaming and logical replication on same primary host & synchronous replication for both

You certainly can have more than one entry in synchronous_standby_names:
synchronous_standby_names = 2 (standby1, standby2)

standby1 and standby2 are the application_names set for the respective replication connections.
